# CQ5 textfield validation with regex

Tags: regex, extjs, aem

I have a simple CQ dialog with a textfield. The authors somehow managed to paste illegal characters into it, the last two times it was a vertical tab (VT) copied from a PowerPoint file. 
I played around with some regex and came up with the following to exclude anything below SPACE and DEL:

```
/^[^\0-\x1F\x7F]*$/
```

Sadly I can't really test the vertical tab as I am not able to enter this character on regex101. So I tried it with TAB and this seems to be working: https://regex101.com/r/yH0lN5/1

But if I use this in my `regex` property of the `textfield`, no matter what I enter the validation fails. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

White listing isn't an option as i need to support Unicode characters like chinese in the future.

Comment: Try `regex="/^[^\\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]*$/"`

Comment: @stribizhev thanks, could have thought of that myself. If you post it as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should double the backslashes to make sure they are treated as literal backslashes by the regex engine.

Also, I suggest using consistent notation, and replace `\0` with `\x00`:

```
regex="/^[^\\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]*$/"
```

And this regex just matches entires strings that contain zero or more characters (due to `*`) other than (due to the negated character class used `[^...]`) the ones from the NUL to US character (`[\x00-\x1F]`) and a DEL character (`\x7F`):

[image]

Comment: thanks for the extended answer and yes, this is what I am trying to do. Maybe I need to add some other chars later, but for the moment I only want to get rid of any of the control chars, even if they would be printable like HT, CR and LF

Comment: Good. Just note that if you plan to add a literal ``\``, you will have to quadruple it as ``\\\\``. And as for the double quote, perhaps, you might have to use `\\x22`, but maybe escaping it will be enough.